# Mistake by deleting my Phpmyadmin database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I accidently drop my database **phpmyadmin.**
How can I restore it. Actually when I click on database, I got this message.
Someone can help me
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps to create new 'phpmyadmin' database:

1. Step 1 :Use MySQL command line client or MySQL workbench to create the 'phpmyadmin' database.
2. Step 2: Use following SQL command to create tables :

> ```
>     --
> -- Database: `phpmyadmin`
> --
>
>
> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
> START TRANSACTION;
> SET time_zone = "+00:00";
>
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
>
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__bookmark`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__bookmark` (
>   `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `dbase` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `user` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `label` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `query` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Bookmarks';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__central_columns`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__central_columns` (
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `col_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `col_type` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `col_length` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
>   `col_collation` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `col_isNull` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>   `col_extra` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
>   `col_default` text COLLATE utf8_bin
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Central list of columns';
>
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__column_info`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__column_info` (
>   `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `column_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `comment` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `mimetype` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `transformation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `transformation_options` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `input_transformation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Column information for phpMyAdmin';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__designer_settings`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__designer_settings` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `settings_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Settings related to Designer';
>
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__export_templates`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__export_templates` (
>   `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `export_type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `template_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `template_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Saved export templates';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__favorite`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__favorite` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `tables` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Favorite tables';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__history`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__history` (
>   `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `db` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `table` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `sqlquery` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__navigationhiding`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__navigationhiding` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `item_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `item_type` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__pdf_pages`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__pdf_pages` (
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `page_nr` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `page_descr` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__recent`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__recent` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `tables` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Recently accessed tables';
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__relation`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__relation` (
>   `master_db` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `master_table` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `master_field` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `foreign_db` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `foreign_table` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `foreign_field` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Relation table';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__savedsearches`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__savedsearches` (
>   `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `search_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `search_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Saved searches';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_coords`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__table_coords` (
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `pdf_page_number` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `x` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `y` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_info`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__table_info` (
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `display_field` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Table information for phpMyAdmin';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_uiprefs`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__table_uiprefs` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `prefs` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences';   
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__userconfig`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__userconfig` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `config_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='User preferences storage for phpMyAdmin';
>
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__usergroups`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__usergroups` (
>   `usergroup` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `tab` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `allowed` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items';
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__users`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__users` (
>   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `usergroup` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups';
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__tracking`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `pma__tracking` (
>   `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `version` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
>   `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
>   `schema_snapshot` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `schema_sql` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
>   `data_sql` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin,
>   `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME  TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL, `tracking_active` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin';
> -------------------------------------------------------- 
> --
> -- Indexes for dumped tables
> --
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__bookmark`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__bookmark`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__central_columns`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__central_columns`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`col_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__column_info`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__column_info`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   ADD UNIQUE KEY `db_name` (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__designer_settings`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__designer_settings`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__export_templates`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__export_templates`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   ADD UNIQUE KEY `u_user_type_template` (`username`,`export_type`,`template_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__favorite`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__favorite`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__history`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__history`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   ADD KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__navigationhiding`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__navigationhiding`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__pdf_pages`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__pdf_pages`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`page_nr`),
>   ADD KEY `db_name` (`db_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__recent`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__recent`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__relation`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__relation`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),
>   ADD KEY `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__savedsearches`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__savedsearches`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   ADD UNIQUE KEY `u_savedsearches_username_dbname` (`username`,`db_name`,`search_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__table_coords`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__table_coords`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__table_info`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__table_info`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__table_uiprefs`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__table_uiprefs`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__tracking`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__tracking`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__userconfig`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__userconfig`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__usergroups`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__usergroups`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `pma__users`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__users`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`);
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
> --
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__bookmark`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__bookmark`
>   MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__column_info`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__column_info`
>   MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__export_templates`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__export_templates`
>   MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__history`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__history`
>   MODIFY `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__pdf_pages`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__pdf_pages`
>   MODIFY `page_nr` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `pma__savedsearches`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `pma__savedsearches`
>   MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
> COMMIT;
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> ```

Done